# How can I route my Angular 2 App so I can use my own Slim Framework API?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, slim, angular2-routing

I made the backend of an application using Slim Framework v3 and the frontend using Angular 2, both of them work well separately but now I 'm trying to combine them but only Angular 2 works fine, and when I try to use Slim with Postman it shows me:

> Cannot GET /rest/users

I am using Angular Cli and I put the Slim files in the src folder of Angular 2.

So how can I route them to use them both and have Angular 2 at the root of my public folder? Or how I have to use Slim so it works fine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not have a webserver running. With ngserve you create a server for angular (but that server does not support PHP), with php -S you setup a server for the php files, which also have no problem with JS files.

So I would just setup a WAMP/LAMP stack on the machine you are using (Windows/Linux + Apache + Mysql/MariaDB + PHP). Then start it up and test your app :).

Answer (score 0):

Ok It seems that if I use `ng serve` from angular cli it doesnt works fine but if I use `php -S localhost:8080` it works fine and it all routes fine.